# Aws load balancer for Server Sent Events or Websockets

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, server-sent-events, amazon-elb

I'm trying to load balance a nodejs Server sent event backend and I need to know if there is a way to distribute the new connections to the instances with the least connected clients. The problem I have is when scaling up, the routing continues sending new connections to the already saturated instance and since the connections are long lived this simply won't work.

What options do I have for horizontal scaling long lived connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a Load Balancer that can provide both "sticky sessions" and use the "least connection" instead of "round-robin" policy. Unfortunately, NGINX cannot provide this.

HAProxy (High Availability Proxy) allows for this:

```
backend bk_myapp
 cookie MyAPP insert indirect nocache
 balance leastconn
 server srv1 10.0.0.1:80 check cookie srv1
 server srv2 10.0.0.2:80 check cookie srv2
```

If you need ELB functionality and want to roll it all manually, take a look at this [guide](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-on-aws-best-practices-part-2/).

You might also want to make sure classic AWS ELB "sticky session" [configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) or the newer [ALB "sticky session"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) option does not meet your needs. ELB normally sends connection to upstream server with the least "load", and when combining with sticky sessions might be enough.

Comment: Yes I'll look at that. Sticky sessions are working fine and I use redis to share state between the nodes. The configuration article is about classic load balancer, which I though was going to be removed from aws.

Comment: This works with classic load balancer, however close events from the client do not make it to the backend now.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using AWS, I'd recommend [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk) for your Node.js application deployment. The official documentation provides good examples, like [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html). Note that Beanstalk will [automatically create an Elastic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html) for you, which is what you're looking for.

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk creates an Application Load Balancer for
> your environment when you enable load balancing with the Elastic
> Beanstalk console or the EB CLI. It configures the load balancer to
> listen for HTTP traffic on port 80 and forward this traffic to
> instances on the same port.
>
> [...]
>
> Note:
> Your environment must be in a VPC with subnets in at least two
> Availability Zones to create an Application Load Balancer. All new AWS
> accounts include default VPCs that meet this requirement. If your
> environment is in a VPC with subnets in only one Availability Zone, it
> defaults to a Classic Load Balancer. If you don't have any subnets,
> you can't enable load balancing.

Note that the [configuration of a proper health check path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html#using-features.healthstatus.understanding) is key to properly balance requests, as you mentioned in your question.

> In a load balanced environment, Elastic Load Balancing sends a request
> to each instance in an environment every 10 seconds to confirm that
> instances are healthy. By default, the load balancer is configured to
> open a TCP connection on port 80. If the instance acknowledges the
> connection, it is considered healthy.
>
> You can choose to override this setting by specifying an existing
> resource in your application. If you specify a path, such as /health,
> the health check URL is set to HTTP:80/health. The health check URL
> should be set to a path that is always served by your application. If
> it is set to a static page that is served or cached by the web server
> in front of your application, health checks will not reveal issues
> with the application server or web container.

EDIT: If you're looking for sticky sessions, as I described in the comments, follow the steps provided in [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions):

> To enable sticky sessions using the console
>
> 1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
> 2. On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Target Groups.
> 3. Select the target group.
> 4. On the Description tab, choose Edit attributes.
> 5. On the Edit attributes page, do the following:
>
> a. Select Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness.
>
> b. For Stickiness duration, specify a value between 1 second and 7 days.
>
> c. Choose Save.

Comment: I'm using Beanstalk. My question is how to configure routing to the instances so they dont over load a single instance. The connections persist and can last hours. It is currently using round robin to distribute new requests and this wont work.

Comment: Are you looking for the ["sticky sessions" mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions)? Ideally, you should go stateless for better scalability.